# I want to convert the code below into Cupertino, IOS style. But I Can't Use Drawer Menu for IOS style. Why? How can I use?

Tags: ios, flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-cupertino

I want to make android and IOS style.

I want to convert the code below into Cupertino, IOS style.

But I Can't Use Drawer Menu for IOS style. Why?
How can I use?

```
return Scaffold(
    key: _scaffoldKey,
    drawer: Drawer(),
    appBar: AppBar(
      leading: IconButton(
        onPressed: () {
          Navigator.pop(context);
        },
        icon: Icon(
          Icons.arrow_back_ios,
          color: MyColors.blue,
        ),
      ),
      centerTitle: true,
      title: Text('Test', style: MyTextStyles.appBarTitle(deviceType) ),
      actions: <Widget>[
        Builder(
          builder: (BuildContext context) => PlatformIconButton(
            onPressed: () {
              Scaffold.of(context).openDrawer();
            },
            icon: Icon(
              Icons.menu,
            )))])
    body: .........
```

Comment: You can't create a Drawer when using Cupertino (iOS style). Thats because Drawer is exclusive to Material (Android style). You can check that [here](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/design/drawer)

Comment: I can add. By stack or some other method. But I'm looking for a more practical easy way.

Comment: [Check this](https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/macos/windows-and-views/drawers/) about drawers on iOS. Of course you can handle a custom creation of a Drawer but there is a reason why Flutter don't provide it by default for iOS

Comment: Thank you for information my friend :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Drawer` widget is a Material-exclusive widget, and you can't use it directly on iOS.

You could build your own "Drawer-like" widget for iOS by replicating the build construction of a `Drawer` widget, but I would not recommend that, because drawers don't have that iOS "look and feel". As an iOS user myself, I know some very influential apps like Twitter have something that looks like a Drawer, but I think that is not the way a native iOS app would handle that kind of navigation.

What you can do instead, is having a `Drawer` widget for Android, and a bottom tab bar for iOS, which is a component that is way more common in iOS-styled apps. You can use the `Platform` class to check if your code is being executed on Android or iOS, and choose the right widget based on that.

Here is one example of such a build logic that you might find useful. I am very sorry I can't paste the code directly, I had this screenshot from a presentation I made and I don't remember where did I place the code for this project, but I hope you find it useful.[image]